# Prove $\text{Cov}[{(Z'Z)}^{-1}Z'Y|X]={(Z'Z)}^{-1}Z'\text{Cov}[Y|Z]Z{(Z'Z)}^{-1}$

Tags: regression, proof

I'm reading a proof of the covariance matrix of the LS estimator
$$
\text{Cov}[{(Z'Z)}^{-1}Z'Y|X]={(Z'Z)}^{-1}Z'\text{Cov}[Y|Z]Z{(Z'Z)}^{-1}
$$
where $Z$ is the design matrix, $Y$ the response variable and $X$ the explanatory variable.
I'm wondering why it works?

Comment: Not easy to answer without a proper explanation of the notation. The traditional case would be $Z=X$. Maybe $X$ denotes some general information set?

Comment: Are you sure that in the right hand side you actually meant $cov[Y|Z])$ and not $cov[Y|X]$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that $\text{Cov}(AX)=A'\text{Cov}(X)A$.

This is a simple fact resulting from the definition of covariance in the lower dimensions.